# Gravity Forms Text Hint

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

Does anyone know a way to display a line of text when a user has selected a specific item in a dropdown menu? I can setup a conditional to display another form element on select, but I need it to just display a piece of text for a hint. Can't seem to figure it out!

Comment: I asked for help on exactly what I needed. If there is something unclear, please explain instead of down voting. If you read everything you will see what I am asking for. I need to have a piece of text appear when a user selects a specific item in the dropdown, using the Gravity Forms Wordpress plugin. It is a very common feature on forms, but I need to integrate it into Gravity Forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this will be to show/hide an HTML field with your hint based on the option selected. You can then use CSS to position the field wherever you want the hint to display. Gravity Forms [Ready Classes](https://www.gravityhelp.com/css-ready-classes-for-gravity-forms/) will make this even easier.

Comment: Thank you!! I see what you mean now